# saving a page in python and firefox as xlsx

Tags: python, excel, firefox, urllib, xlsx

when I save [this](http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0) link through my firefox built in downloader, it give me a usable xlsx file which I can open by excel or libreoffic. but when I try to download it by aria2c or `urllib.request.urlretrieve` in a python code I encounter to a problem which the saved file is unusable. why this problem happen? can you give me a python code which store the usable xlsx file from the above link?

Comment: I suggest you edit the question to include the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach should do what you need:

```
import requests
import re
import os

xlsx_req = requests.get("http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0")
xlsx_filename = os.path.basename(re.findall("filename=(.+)", xlsx_req.headers['content-disposition'])[0])

with open(xlsx_filename, 'wb') as f_xlsx:
    f_xlsx.write(xlsx_req.content)
```

This uses requests to download the file. It also extracts the filename to use from the `content-disposition` header.